# Sharepoint error logging by the system

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have worked on PHP (LAMP) initially and now I have started working on Sharepoint. In case of PHP all the errors were captured and shown in Apache Error Log in case of Sharepoint I have to use Try and Catch block and then use the code shown below to capture the error. This is working fine for me. No issues with it. But the downside is - I have to be vigilant enough to make sure that I put Try Catch every possible place.

I want something like PHP, i.e. to log things automatically. Please help.

```
  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {

                    SPDiagnosticsService diagSvc = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
                    SPDiagnosticsCategory cat = diagSvc.Areas["SharePoint Foundation"].Categories["Unknown"];
                    string format = "Test trace logging gggg for category {0} in area {1}";
                    diagSvc.WriteTrace(1, cat, TraceSeverity.Medium, format, cat.Name, cat.Area.Name);       
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will ahve to deal with the errors yourself. Sharepoint implements its own logs but only for the things it wants to handle. Extended errors or custom error logging must be implemented by you.

In my case, I usually use base classes for my webparts, layouts and classes and code the error handling in a single place. Any class element inheriting this base classess automatically handles errors.

Anyway, you could implement a custom service and log erros to ULS or create similar base classes for your common elements. Take a look to this article that might help you out. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Every unhandled exception in SharePoint is logged to ULS automatically as a message with the *Unexpected* level. You should not need to implement any logging if you are fine with that. Also avoid catching exceptions you cannot handle as recommended [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413949.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions in ASP.NET bubble up the call stack if not handled, ultimately you can implement a Module that handles the errors. You can see an exemple here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16171/An-HTTP-Module-for-ASP-NET-Error-Handling

How do you deploy it? You can deploy it using a farm solution and to add it to web config use the spwebconfigmodification class